# Can you use the Horcrux ritual to "re-ensoul" someone who's had their soul removed?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

As I was reading Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows today I thought of a question about Horcruxes. **Can only the person who created the Horcrux use it, or can the Horcrux be used by a body that has, say, had its soul removed by a [Dementor's Kiss](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dementor's_Kiss)?**

Would it just be the *body* of the person who had the soul removed, and the new soul would be that of the person who created the Horcrux?

Comment: What do you mean use a Horcrux?

Comment: @Edlothiad - I've re-worded it to make it a little clearer (I think).

Comment: do you mean like possession?

Comment: @NKCampbell - I think that's precisely what he means. Take an unsouled body, drop a soul fragment into it "ta-da!" instant clone.

Comment: It's clearer but I still don't understand how one would "use a Horcrux"?

Comment: @Edlothiad - The Horcrux ritual places a soul piece in a container. If that container is a suitable being, but one without a soul, can you use the ritual to take over (possess) that un-souled container?

Comment: @Valorum, oh they mean the ritual?! I thought they're taking one of the Horcruxes and stuffing it in themselves.

Comment: See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8899/what-effect-would-the-dementors-kiss-have-on-voldemort-prior-to-the-destruction bottom line we don't know what would happen

Comment: Right now I'm imagining the ritual of making someone whose soul has been sucked swallow a horcrux.

Answer (score 3):

There's no canonical answer that I'm aware of, but it looks like the answer could be yes.

Chamber of Secrets:

> The diary horcrux possesses a level of independent animus, suggesting that a soul is the thing that makes a person a person. Also, we see that a soul can be sustained or reinvigorated by the life from another person.

Deathly Hallows:

> We see, after Harry confronts Voldemort in the forest, that a fragment of Voldemort's soul exists as a definite entity within Harry - one living being's soul inside the body of another.

Taking the two together, it suggests that you could indeed shunt a portion of your soul into the body of someone who'd previously been kissed by a Dementor, and effectively duplicate yourself. I suspect that it would be frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

This has long been a subject that has interested me.
The question being; Can you make a horcrux from a person who has had their soul removed by a Dementor?
In my opinion, yes you can.
The first step being to align yourself with a group of Dementors. (Only 1 will suffice)
The second is to choose witches/wizards who posses great potential and strong lineage*
*Latter inconsequential.
Ensure you are proficient in the curses and protective charms required to create a viable horcrux. (First and foremost.)

After disarming and subduing your target (dueling quickly and humanely, although the cruciatis curse beforehand may help with the necessary isolation of the soul fragment). Employ a Dementor to perform the Kiss. 
This should be enough to create the required soul fragment, however use of avada kerdava on another victim should ensure that the soul fragment is sufficiently isolated.
Now, have the person kissed by a Dementor.
You now have;
Their soul removed and their body untouched and healthy. Along with the desired fragment.

Begin with the protective charms required to protect "the container"
Follow this up with the necessary spells required to create your horcrux.
Assuming that the ritual was successful and your enchantments were cast correctly, your horcrux is now a witch/wizard protected by powerful dark magic and an exact copy of you in every way. Each of you alive while the other survives.

Now imagine creating another like this but of the opposite sex, then imagine if they had children of their own. Would a horcrux dynasty be possible?

Comment: While an interesting line of thought, this seems to be purely speculative. Answers on SciFi.StackExchange should typically be based on sources rather than pure conjecture.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't re-ensoul someone because the magic process separates the killer's soul when he/she commits a murder. That's the reason why you have to kill someone, because the act of killing someone is so terrible that you loose a part of your soul. With the "magic process" you can stock this piece of soul on an object.

I can't post any J.K. Rowling explanation, sorry. I read two articles and a twitter answer on where she explain that.

Comment: Could you provide the articles and twitter answers as a source? it would strengthen your answer!

Comment: I'm at work now, so I can't, I try it later. Thanks for the advice, I'm new at that web! :)

Comment: Are you still at work?

Comment: ups, sorry, you can read the answer here: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Horcrux

"To create a Horcrux, a wizard first had to deliberately commit murder. This act, said to be one of supreme evil, would result in the murderer metaphysically damaging their own soul. A wizard who wished to create a Horcrux would then use that damage to their advantage by casting a spell which would rip the damaged portion of the soul and encase it in an object."